# How do I change column default value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How do I change column default value in PostgreSQL?

I've tried:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY users ALTER COLUMN lang DEFAULT 'en_GB';
```

But it gave me an error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
```

Answer (score 400, accepted):

'SET' is forgotten

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY users ALTER COLUMN lang SET DEFAULT 'en_GB';
```

Comment: What for `ONLY` is used before the name of the table?

Comment: "If ONLY is specified before the table name, only that table is altered. If ONLY is not specified, the table and all its descendant tables (if any) are altered"
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 127):

If you want to remove the default value constraint, you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE <table> ALTER COLUMN <column> DROP DEFAULT;
```