# SQL Error when trying to alter column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I add trying to add a method to be the defualt value of an existing SQL Table Column:

```
 ALTER TABLE Category ALTER COLUMN category_course 
   CONSTRAINT cat_other_course DEFAULT otherCourse();
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CONSTRAINT"
LINE 2: ALTER TABLE Category ALTER COLUMN category_course CONSTRAINT...
                                                      ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "CONSTRAINT"
SQL state: 42601
```

NB: Yes, Category (table) category_course (column) and otherCourse() (function) all exist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4745365/3270427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add SET before DEFAULT. Hope this helps.

```
ALTER TABLE Category ALTER COLUMN category_course 
CONSTRAINT cat_other_course SET DEFAULT otherCourse();
```