# Add a default text value for a column in postgres table

Tags: database, postgresql, text, default-value, alter-table

How do I add a default value to a text column in postgres table,example "There is no message"
tried the below:
alter table messages alter column message set default ="There is no message"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change column default value in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745156/how-do-i-change-column-default-value-in-postgresql)

Comment: Thanks for the link , it helped. one more question am trying to retrieve a column's null values in postgres sql but not able to do so: the values in the column are <null>, I tried where column='null', '', is null, '<null>' '0', but there are lot of null values in the table, but not able to retrieve the same.

Comment: `where column is null` or maybe `where column is null or column = ''`